# Convert array to Request object in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have store method in user controller like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create($request->all()); 

}
```

and in another controller I want use this method

```
 public function test(Request $request)
{
  .....
   app('\App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->store($test_array);
  ...
}
```

and `$test_array` is:

```
{"name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com"}
```

and finally show me error this

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\UserController::store() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request,

How can I convert array to Request object?

Comment: How do you get `$request` array before `app('\App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->store($request);`?

Comment: Why is $request an argument to `test` in the first place? You would be better off using `setUp` or a data provider

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just use

```
$request = new Illuminate\Http\Request($test_array);
```

Answer (score 8):

use `$request->merge($someArray)`

You can try this way..

Your second controller's test method.

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
  $another_array = [];
  $another_array['eg'] = $test_array;
  $request->merge($another_array);

  .....
   app('\App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->store($request->get('eg'));
  ...
}
```

Your`$test_array`must be of the type `array`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to use `store()` this way.

If you're calling `store()` action from other places, you could place persisting logic into a model:

```
class User extends Model

    public function storeData($data)
    {
        $createdUser = User::create($data);
        return $createdUser;
    }
```

And then call this from `store()` action and `test()`.

If not just, just change `store()` to:

```
public function store($data)
{
    User::create($data); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey but I can't add method in model because before that I added any method in controller

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I mean. You can put DB related logic inside a model class. Then you'll be able to call it from any controller and any action you want (from `test()` and from `store()`). That's the right use of MVC pattern.

Comment: I have validation and another thing in store method of user controller and I if I use in model I write this in test controller `User::create($request); `

Comment: That's why Laravel allows you to create custom Request class for validation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert array to Request object?

If you really want to do it this way, which I wouldn't, here you're:

Something like this should do the trick -- I did not test it:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as SymfonyRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request as IlluminateRequest;


$symfonyRequest = SymfonyRequest::createFromGlobals();

$symfonyRequest->query = new ParameterBag([
    'foo' => 'bar',
]);

$request = IlluminateRequest::createFromBase($symfonyRequest);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use redirect using flashed session data? As the [Response - Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) documentation says:

> Redirecting to a new URL and flashing data to the session are
>   typically done at the same time. So, for convenience, you may create a
>   RedirectResponse instance and flash data to the session in a single
>   method chain. This is particularly convenient for storing status
>   messages after an action:

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {
    // Update the user's profile...

    return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
});
```

> Of course, after the user is redirected to a new page, you may
>   retrieve and display the flashed message from the session. For
>   example, using Blade syntax:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

So in your case you would store `return redirect('dashboard')->with('user', $userModel);`

Comment: You don't understand my problem, I want to use controller method in other place to REST API